# Android application logo implementation

Tags: android, icons, manifest, drawable, graphical-logo

I have created a logo by using Paint and saved as logo.png.

Now I want to change the default `ic_launcher` logo of android to my logo.

I know that I need to copy my logo to the `res/drawable` folders. I added the same file to all `drawables` and changed android `manifest.xml`. In android manifest I selected "Application" and then changed icon name to `logo.png` instead of `ic_launcher`. I think i need to change the resolutions but I don't know the criteria for `drawable` folders. Do you know how I can customize them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Android Asset Studio [here](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter).

Choose Launcher Icon and pick Image at the top. There you can upload an image and the rest is taken care of for you. You can also edit a few things about the image there and there is also a preview at the bottom. When you are finished click on download .zip at the bottom just above the preview. The zip will contain all the images for all the necessary resolutions.

Comment: But i wonder why it doesnt contain ldpi folder , what should i put in ldpi folder ?

Comment: Nothing. ldpi is pretty much irrelevant nowadays. You are gonna have trouble finding a device that is still ldpi. mdpi is the lowest you encounter normally.

Answer (score 0):

Useful info regarding icon resolutions for different screen densities

[image]